# Problema con Rails gem sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hola a todos espero su pronta ayuda, soy nuevo con ruby on rails y ya tengo este problema que no lo puedo resolver.
Tengo windows 10 64
Ya trate de modificar mi gemfile cambiado gem 'sqlite3' por

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

pero ahora cuando hago bundle install me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Using sqlite3 1.3.13.20180326210955 (was 1.3.13) from https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby (at add-gemspec@1027509)
error: no se pudo iniciar la operación (no se pudo bloquear la base de datos)
error: no se pudo bloquear la base de datos: File exists
  si está seguro de que no se está ejecutando
  un administrador de paquetes, puede quitar /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/sqlite3-ruby-102750907917/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190601-1800-1uavfl9.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-ruby-102750907917/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/sqlite3-ruby-102750907917 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-ruby-102750907917/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13.20180326210955), and Bundler
cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

Tengo instaladas las versiones

- Rails 5.2.3
- ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste tu instalación de **SQLite3**?, ¿qué resultado obtienes si ejecutas `sqlite3 --version` desde la línea de comandos?

Comment: si ejecuto sqlite3 --version me aparece -> "sqlite3" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.Porque es la primera vez que me sucede algo así

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia pero me explicaron que sqlite viene instalado en los sistemas operativos, y no es necesario instalarlo?' O estoy mal

Comment: Al parecer no tienes SQLite en tu sistema o la instalación no es correcta (hasta donde sé SQLite no viene instalado en Windows); te recomiendo visitar la [página de SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) y hacer la instalación.